# SymPy not printing in terminal nicely

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to see nicely formatted multiplication output in an interactive terminal on windows.  The fact I'm not getting the nice output suggests there's something wrong with my setup. I tried (with and without `use_unicode=True` in the call to `init_session()`)

```
from sympy import init_session
init_session()
factor(2*x**2+x)
```

Instead of the factored expression with nice mid-line dots [as shown here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html) representing the multiplication, it produces a factored expression with nonsense character in place of the dots.

Any idea how I get the nice dots? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The problem may simply be the Windows terminal itself: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-unicode-and-utf-8-output-text-buffer/  If you have Spyder, you may want to try running SymPy in the Spyder console and see if you have the same problems.

Comment: It probably is the terminal. It would be nice to know what actions to take to fix it, if it's possible. Should be said it was an Anaconda terminal. In the end I ran a Jupyter/Ipython environment which eventually worked (it prompted to install further libraries),